# What will be the values of phase crossover frequency when the gain margin is infinity?

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, phase-margin

$$G(s) = \frac{s+1}{s^2+2s+100}$$
For the given transfer function I am getting the gain margin equal to infinity in the matlab, but i am not getting the value of phase crossover frequency.

What will be the values of phase crossover frequency when the gain margin is infinity?

Answer (score 2):

> *What will be the values of phase crossover frequency when the gain
> margin is infinity?*

The phase will never cross the 180° point hence, the phase crossover frequency is indeterminate. Because the phase can never reach 180° the concept of gain margin is also null and void in this example.